# How to run script with Django settings in subdirectory without relative project path

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to execute the `seeds.py` script located in `restaurants_project/scripts/`. This seed file would populate my database with restaurant records based on the CSV data within the same folder by using my Django model `Restaurant`. I've found that the only way to include the project settings (i.e. `restaurant_project.settings`) along with my necessary models was to `sys.path.append('MY_PROJECTS_RELATIVE_PATH')` in the seeds file. I obviously don't want to do this in production (or do i?) so what's the best way to include those settings without getting the following `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'restaurants_project.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 'restaurants_project'
```

`Directory Tree:`

```
|___restaurants_project
| |______init__.py
| |______pycache__
| | |______init__.cpython-34.pyc
| | |____settings.cpython-34.pyc
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____restaurants
| |______init__.py
| |______pycache__
| | |______init__.cpython-34.pyc
| | |____admin.cpython-34.pyc
| | |____models.cpython-34.pyc
| |____admin.py
| |____migrations
| | |______init__.py
| |____models.py
| |____tests.py
| |____views.py
|____scripts
| |______init__.py
| |______pycache__
| | |______init__.cpython-34.pyc
| |____restaurant_inspections_2014.csv
| |____seeds.py
| |____unique_restaurant_ids.txt
```

`seeds.py:`

```
import os, sys
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'restaurants_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import csv
csvfile = open('restaurant_inspections_2014.csv')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
headers = next(reader, None)

for row in reader:
  print(row)
  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to write a script that uses the settings of a project is to write a custom management command:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

Basically you should wrap your script inside a class that extends `BaseCommand` and put it inside the `management/commands` directory of an app.